# Dragging inside Table

Tags: angularjs, html, html-table

I made dragging functionality, but stuck in something, cuz not pRo  . 
Source [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PHCew93buUKDb4584PRp?p=preview)<sup>angularjs</sup>. 
It's about [smart-table](/questions/tagged/smart-table) directive from [<kbd>**lorenzofox3**</kbd>](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table)
But point of question is dragging feature itself.
I know how to drag element, but the problem is that it's a `<table>` with nested

```hmtl
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th>header</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>text</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

And I wonder how steps should be done. Should I replace DOM element positions or just imitate. And also consider i must respectively replace table columns.
I need just steps(*not solution*) of full logic - what must happen when user
 `start-drags` `move-drag` `end-drag`.
Angular approach is not important. Just logic.

#### Answer from lorenzofox3

> Hello,
>
> I think your best bet is to have an associated model to your columns so that you can watch it, and especially when you reorder the collection (by drag n drop for example). Have a look at this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DRagFo?p=preview). 
>   Note to reorder the model collection with drag and drop I use [lrDragNDrop](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/lrDragNDrop) if you are interested in the logic.
>   The drawback with my simple example is that you lose flexibility on the cell templates, and you will have to elaborate a bit on this example if you want something more sophisticated.
>
> regards,
>
> Laurent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular-ui ui-sortable is the way to go with dragging and dropping. I've used it to drag table columns around very successfully.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

adding this in your options helped me with xaxis dragging

```
start: function(e, ui) {
  # since this is a horizontal list, use the known workaround  from
  # https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/issues/19
  $(e.target).data("ui-sortable").floating = true
}
```

The developer is very helpful and responsive.

Comment: @Igersman and ark, i appreciate your help, but my purpose was to make clean directive, without dependencies. I just need logic, as if you try to write it on paper

Comment: @evc good luck! I found drag and drop to be a nightmare and was very grateful for the hard work of the jquery sortable library and the angularization of ui-sortable. Triple the pain if you're trying to support chrome/firefox/ie.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems when dragging table rows and tried several solutions from html5 native dragging to various drag'n drop libraries.

the only working solution so far was using ([jquery-ui sortable and tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307705/jquery-ui-sortable-with-table-and-tr-width)). works like a charm.