# jQuery UI Sortable and Table/Cell Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm having trouble using jQuery UI's `sortable`.

I have a table in which the rows follow this structure:

```
<tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 192, 203);">
    <input type="hidden" name="MyElement.index" autocomplete="off" value="748d4196-c12d-4c61-94f5-ad1a15eb279b">
    <td style="background-color:red;">
        <input type="hidden" id="MyElement_748d4196-c12d-4c61-94f5-ad1a15eb279b__ID" name="MyElement[748d4196-c12d-4c61-94f5-ad1a15eb279b].ID" />
        <input type="hidden" ... />
        <a href="..."> ... </a>
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:green;">
        <a href="..."> ... </a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; width: 12.5%; background-color: blue">
        <a class="cancel-new-element" href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove(); return false;" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 15px;">
            <img src="/Images/icon_remove.png" alt="Remove Row"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The first hidden `input` (named 'MyElement.index') comes from the [`Html.BeginCollectionItem()`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) extension method used to support the editing of a variable length list, an approach I've used several times before and which can be seen [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) or [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/). Basically it adds a prefix to the names and ids of inputs of repeating items (i.e. items in a collection) in a model/viewmodel so that model binding knows which input belongs to which nested object.

I'm also setting a custom helper in my [jQuery UI sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/):

```
var myHelper = function (e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function (index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
    return $helper;
};
```

so that [the td's in the row being dragged keep their widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307705/jquery-ui-sortable-with-table-and-tr-width?rq=1).

However, I don't get the desired effect and instead, when I drag a row, the table shrinks a bit and I can see that the cells of the row being dragged aren't really keeping their exact widths.

1) This is the table (tr and td's backgrounds have been coloured for better visualization):
[image: Table]

2) The last row is being dragged. You can see that the table size decreases and the td's widths change in the dragged row. Pink is the row's background.
[image: Table with item being dragged]

If I don't use the `BeginCollectionItem` - which I need to in order to successfully post my ViewModel - I don't get the same issue.

I have tried several modifications on my `myHelper` function. including removing the hidden `input` from the `$helper` object, with no results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found my solution here: [jquery UI Sortable with table and tr width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307705/jquery-ui-sortable-with-table-and-tr-width) (@Keith's answer).

```
// Fix the width of the cells
$('td, th', '#tableId').each(function () {
    var cell = $(this);
    cell.width(cell.width());
});

$('#tableBodyId').sortable({
    items: '> tr',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    start: function (event, ui) {
        // Build a placeholder cell that spans all the cells in the row
        var cellCount = 0;
        $('td, th', ui.helper).each(function () {
            // For each td or th try and get it's colspan attribute, and add that or 1 to the total
            var colspan = 1;
            var colspanAttr = $(this).attr('colspan');
            if (colspanAttr > 1) {
                colspan = colspanAttr;
            }
            cellCount += colspan;
        });

        // Add the placeholder UI - note that this is the item's content, so td rather than tr
        ui.placeholder.html('<td colspan="' + cellCount + '">&nbsp;</td>');
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

(JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rp4fV/4/))

Also, whenever I modify the table (e.g. append new rows...) I clear the widths set like so

```
// Clear the fixed widths: 
$('td, th', '#sortFixed').each(function () {
    var cell = $(this);
    cell.css('width','');
});
```

and then re-fix the widths.

Credit goes to [@Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905/keith), for the original answer.