# Can a jQuery widget be used in a table

Tags: jquery, widget, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use the jQuery sortable widget in a table. Is that feasible? Or is it made to be separate from a table?

This is the link to the jQuery widget-

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply the sortable() method to the appropriate tbody element. There are bug fixes regarding width maintenance which are addressed [here](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/), so you should apply that to your tablesorter initialization.

```
var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
    ui.children().each(function() {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
    });
    return ui;
};

$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelper
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks..but this is for sorting.Can I also implement the same for reoderer the table rows like what is shown in the link I posted above.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. So you're looking for row reordering like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/tzYbU/)?

Comment: Yes..exactly like that!

Comment: I have edited my answer so others aren't victims of my misunderstanding. Please note that this question has also been addressed before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307705/jquery-ui-sortable-with-table-and-tr-width/1372954#1372954