# Sortable rubaxa hide floating ghost but not actual row

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, draggable, rubaxa-sortable

I am using [Sortable from Rubaxa](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) to sort rows from a Bootstrap table.

The table rows have cells which include Bootstrap inputs.

Now, the rows sort alright, but the "ghost" image only shows buttons which are in the row, not the inputs. I want to include the inputs in this "ghost" image, or even better; do not show the actual "ghost" image at all.

A suggestion for a better solution than Sortable is appreciated as well, I just want to drag rows from a Bootstrap table in a particular order, no floating "ghost" image needed/wanted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For future reference, I solved my issue by disregarding Sortable from Rubaxa and by using [sortable()](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) of jQuery UI and by using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16687620/2976720).